# How can I automatically import my existing GitHub repositories in my development story?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, developer-story

Currently I see no way to import repositories as we were used to do with the traditional CV. Is it me or this feature is not available anymore in Developer Stories?

Answer (score 1):

To import a GitHub repository into your Developer Story page:

- Open your [Developer Story page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/story/current)
- Scroll down to **Add a new item** and click **Open source**
- Click **Import from GitHub**

[image: Import from GitHub button]